# Git alias for commit with branch name

Tags: bash, git, github, unix

I'm trying to create a simple bash alias to commit with my branch name in MacOs. For instance, if my branch if CS-12 I'd usually commit as follows:

`git commit /file/location/myfile -m "CS-12 my message goes in here"`

So I'm trying to create an alias which will receive only the file name and the message, ie:

`gcm /file/location/myfile "my message goes in here"`

I've got the following but it's not working:

`alias gcm="echo git commit $1 -m  \"$(current_branch) - $2\""`

where `current_branch` is the function:

```
function current_branch() {
  ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) || \
  ref=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD 2> /dev/null) || return
  echo ${ref#refs/heads/}
}
```

which does work.

The output of running my alias:

`gcm src/pages/register/Register.js "aasdasd asdasd"`

is giving me back:

`git commit -m master -  src/pages/register/Register.js aasdasd asdasd`

any idea what I'm doing wrong? Bash is not my area of expertise.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The escaped quotes are 'stripped' by `alias`, so you need to escape them once more:

```
alias x="echo \\\"foo\\\""
x
"foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

aliases do not take parameters.  Just write a function:

```
gcm() { git commit "$1" -m  "$(current_branch) - $2"; }
```

Note that there's really no need for aliases, and you shouldn't use them.  Since at least 1996, the bash man page has stated: "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions."

Comment: To add on to this, the `$1` and `$2` are expanded when the alias is defined.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried this but I'm getting
```bash: /Users/bigweld/.bash_profile: line 60: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /Users/bigweld/.bash_profile: line 60: `gcm() { git commit "$1" -m "$(current_branch) - $2"; }'
```

Comment: one more think. When "$(current_branch) - $2" with `gcm src/pages/register/Register.js "aasdasd asdasd"` ,notice that the passed message is already in " ", does that mean that I'll have some broken message? ie: `git commit src/pages/register/Register.js -m "CS-12 - " aasdasd asdasd " "`?

Comment: @MrCujo No, when you invoke the function, the quotes are removed.  eg, if you call `gcm foo "a b c"`, the value of `$2` in the function is just the string `a b c`.  It's no different than calling `gcm foo a\ b\ c`; the quotes are there to prevent the argument from being split.

Comment: @MrCujo I believe the syntax error occurs because you still have the alias defined. Remove the alias definition before defining the function.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I had removed the alias before creating the function so the error should no be related to the alias